# Rollback DML statement in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In pgAdmin, if I execute an insert query, I don't see any way to either commit or rollback the statement I just ran (I know it auto commits). I'm used to Oracle and SQL developer, where I could run a statement, and then rollback the last statement I ran with a press of a button. How would I achieve the same thing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use transaction in the SQL window:

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE foo;
ROLLBACK; -- or COMMIT;
```

-- edit --
Another example:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES ('baz') RETURNING bar; -- the results will be returned
SELECT * FROM other_table; -- some more result
UPDATE other_table SET var = 'bla' WHERE id = 1 RETURNING *; -- the results will be returned

-- and when you're done with all statements and have seen the results:
ROLLBACK; -- or COMMIT
```

Comment: hmm, if I'm doing an insert between begin and rollback, with postgres should i expect to be able to see the changes in the table data? or is this not supported?

Comment: Of course it's supported, it's normal behavior of a database.

Answer (score 9):

I also **DEARLY** prefer the Oracle way of putting everything in a transaction automatically, to help avoid catastrophic manual mistakes.

Having auto-commit enabled by default in an ***Enterprise*** product, IMO, is beyond vicious, and nothing but a ***COMPLETELY, UTTERLY INSANE*** design-choice :(

Anyways --- working with Postgres, one always needs to remember

**BEGIN;**

at the start of manual work or sql-scripts.

As a practical habit: then, when you would say: **COMMIT;** 
in Oracle, I use the line

**END; BEGIN;**

in Postgres which does the same thing, i.e commits the current transaction and immediately starts a new one.

---

When using JDBC or similar, to create a connection, always use some method, e.g. getPGConnection(), that includes:

```
...
Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);
dbConn.setAutoCommit(false);
...
```

to make sure every connection has auto-commit disabled.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using pgAdmin4, you can turn the auto commit and/or auto rollback on and off.

Go to the File drop down menu and select Preferences option. In the SQL editor tab -> Options you can see the options to turn auto commit/rollback on and off.

[Auto commit/rollback option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0F60.png)

Comment: This answers the question, but I've abandoned pgadmin. V4 is just awful, and postgres users everywhere are looking for a better alternative. I've settled on dbeaver - https://dbeaver.com/